# Put a box and shade it around aligned equations

Tags: equations, align, miktex

Given:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Sam Keene}
\title{Notes}
\begin{document}
\section{Notes}

\begin{align}
\tan{\theta} &= \frac{2t}{1-t^2} & 
\sin{\theta} &= \frac{2t}{1+t^2} & 
\cos{\theta} &= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I know I can put a box around individual equations using \Aboxed, but how could I put a box around the entire group and have it shaded?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks! I've added in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,ams align,drop fuzzy shadow,
  colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=yellow!50!black]
\tan{\theta} &= \frac{2t}{1-t^2} &
\sin{\theta} &= \frac{2t}{1+t^2} &
\cos{\theta} &= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Or like this  ;)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}    %% not needed, loaded by empheq
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%% box from tcolorbox manual
\newtcbox{\otherbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
enhanced,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=green!10!white,
bottom color=green!10!white,middle color=green!50!yellow},
fuzzy halo=1pt with green,#1}
\author{Sam Keene}
\title{Notes}
\begin{document}
\section{Notes}

\begin{empheq}[box=\otherbox]{align}
\tan{θ} &= \frac{2t}{1-t²} &
\sin{θ} &= \frac{2t}{1+t²} &
\cos{θ} &= \frac{1-t²}{1+t²}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]